# Polynomial transforms in regression result in multiple p-values for each variable. Is there a single, proxy value that can represent these p-values?

Tags: python, regression, statsmodels, polynomials, p-value

I use Python's `statsmodels.formula.api` for most regression tasks. When I test a large number of variables in a model, I check their p-values to be confident that the variables are actually improving the model.

I usually apply polynomial transformations to variables to test whether that improves the fit. For example, this is the equation for a polynomial transform of 3 degrees to variable *x*:

> *ŷ* = *C* + *β₁x* + *β₂x²* + *β₃x³*

My problem is that each term of the variable *x* has its own p-value. That is, there's a separate p-value for the *x*, *x²* and *x³* terms.

In a multivariate regression model, where the predictors *X* comprises *n* individual variables *x₁*, *x₁*, ... *xₙ*, I have no way to assess the p-value of *xᵢ* if I applied a polynomial transform to it.

In this code, I apply a 3-degree polynomial transform to *X*:

```
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf

X = data["predictor"]
y = data["outcome"]

model = smf.ols(
    formula="outcome ~ predictor + I(predictor**2) + I(predictor**3)",
    data=data
)
results = model.fit()

print(results.pvalues)
```

This will yield 4 p-values: one for the constant/intercept, and one for each term of *X*. Can I somehow combine the p-values of *X*, or otherwise develop a proxy measure for them that is a single value?

Comment: `combine_terms` option in `wald_test_terms` is designed for this case, if there is a substring in the names that identifies the variables that should be combined `https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.OLSResults.wald_test_terms.html

Comment: Otherwise, you can use `wald_test` and specify the list of names explicitly.

Comment: In a model that only includes a constant and then powers of the same variable, you can test them jointly using `f_pvalue` which is the p-val for `fvalue`, the F-statistic.